# pass a value from jsp to classic asp page

Tags: jsp, asp-classic

I have 2 pages - 1st jsp page and 2nd asp page.Onclick of a link in jsp page, it opens the asp page. now I need to pass the selected dropdown value from jsp to asp page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use a query parameter, like http://yoursite/yourpage.asp?param=value